# Displaying a date with a leading zero in the input C++

Tags: c++, date, int

I am currently trying to create a header file that takes information from a user and displays information in a form.

For the most part, I have had no problem, however, I need the user to input their date of birth in the format MMDDYYYY, and then convert it to MM/DD/YYYY and display it in the form.

My problem is that if the user inputs the month '01-09', what displayed was nowhere near correct. I still need to display the month the exact way the user input it, so it has to be displayed as (i.e. 01/01/1967).

The variable for the patient's date of birth is called `int patientDateOfBirth`.
 This data type cannot be changed, it has to be an int.

The method in the header file that I am using is as follows:

```
void PatientDemographicInformation::printPatientDateOfBirth( )
{
    int userMonth, userDay, userYear;
    String birthDate = String(itoa(patientDateOfBirth));

    // Calculation to determine month, day, and year from the MMDDYYYY format.
    userMonth = scanf ("%d", &userMonth);
    // this was another method I used, however the leading zero messed it up.
    // userMonth = patientDateOfBirth / 1000000;
    userDay   = patientDateOfBirth / 10000 % 100;
    userYear  = patientDateOfBirth % 10000; 

    cout << userMonth <<  "/";
    cout << setfill('0') << setw(2) << userDay   <<  "/";
    cout << userYear;
}
```

Also, this is the first time I am using this forum, so if my formatting is off, please forgive me.  I also have little experience with this language, so if the answer is simple, please go easy on me!

Thank you.

EDIT: I've just noticed that there is the variable `String birthDate` that is not used in the calculation.  I was not sure if converting the int into a String would work, but I gave it a shot regardless, but it did not work and I forgot to remove that variable.  If that could work, however, please let me know.

EDIT: Sorry if I wasn't as clear as I had hoped to be.  I want the user to input a date of birth in the format MMDDYYYY and output it as MM/DD/YYYY, meaning I have to separate the month, day, and year into seperate variables and then put them into a cout statement.
The problem that I am having is if the user puts a 01 thru 09 as the month `(i.e. 01141967)`,
When the method tries to do the calculation, I get some strange number in the output `(i.e. 112230056/00004814/5599932)` or the like.  I am completely stumped by this dilemma.  I've searched forever trying to find some kind of answer and I have tried several methods, all not working.

Comment: Don't use `scanf`. Also, I don't understand very well what is the desired input and output, can you elaborate on that?

Answer (score 1):

The impression you gave is that you have a `patientDateOfBirth` integer, in one the following formats: `mmddyyyy` OR `mddyyyy`, is that correct? If it is, the original

```
int month = patientDateOfBirth / 1000000;
int day = patientDateOfBirth / 10000 % 100;
int year = patientDateOfBirth % 10000;
```

should work ok, regardless of leading zeroes on some original input. An alternative would be using C++11's `<chrono>` classes or Boost's `<boost/date_time.hpp>` for your conversions...